# nextjs dynamic link causes page reload

Tags: next.js, page-refresh, dynamic-url

I'm new to nextjs and trying to list out blogs and on click of blog, the page with dynamic URL blog/[slug].js should load, but the use of **Link** and Router.push(") reloads the page.

**blogs.js**

```
import Link from 'next/link';
const renderBlogs = (blogs) => {
    return blogs.map(blog => <Link href={`/blog/${blog.slug}`}>
            <a key={blog.id}>{blog.title}</a>
        </Link>
    )
}
function Myblogs(props) {
    let blogs = [
        { id: 1, title: "blog 1", slug: "blog-1" },
        { id: 2, title: "blog 2", slug: "blog-2" }
    ]
    return renderBlogs(blogs);
}
export default Myblogs;
```

**blog/[slug].js**

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
const SingleBlog = (props) => {
    const router = useRouter()
    const slug = router.query.slug
    return <>
        <h3>Single Blog</h3>
        <p>{slug}</p>
    </>
}
export default SingleBlog
```

I'm trying to load [slug].js without reloading but somehow **Link** causes the page to reload.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing the `as` prop for the `Link` component. Required for [dynamic pages](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#dynamic-routes).

```js
...etc

const renderBlogs = blogs => (
  blogs.map(({ id, slug, title }) => (
    <Link key={id} href="/blog/[slug]" as={`/blog/${slug}`} >
      <a>{title}</a>
    </Link>
  )            
);

...etc
```

Comment: My issue with using "as" property is that when I reload the page, it shows 404. Do you know how to solve that ?

Comment: This answer is now deprecated. The `as` prop is no longer required for Next v9.5.3 and above.

Comment: but how I will have a custom url to be displayed without "as" property?

Comment: See [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-route-has-dynamic-segments).

Comment: Oh I get this, But what I'm facing is , I need a specific url name to be displayed when routing to a page. Example /About should be /about-website. This was possible with "as", but since its deprecated, what do you suggest?

Comment: You should create a separate question with example code.

Comment: Sure, I already did, but unfortunately no one has answered yet. 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/66005303/10866113