# NextJS Link "as" property doesnt open the page on reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm new to NextJS, Since nextjs has its own router, I wanted to go to a page but the url should be different

```
 <Link href="/About/About" as="/about-page">
        <a>
          Who We Are <img src="svgIcons/down-arrow.svg" alt="" />
        </a>
  </Link>
```

Here my about the file is in the About Folder named About.js. So I can call it in the href as /About/About. But I want to URL to display as /about-page.

Which works as expected. But when I reload that page, it shows 404 Not Found. Which makes sense because /about-page is just an alias. the real page is /About/About.

So how do I solve this issue?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: This goes against the NextJS file structure routing, where the file structure `/src/pages/about.jsx` routes to `/about`. That said, you can use [redirects](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects) as a work-around. But I don't understand why you want point to `/About/About` to redirect to `/about-page`, when you can just point to `/about-page` in the href attribute and have your file be `about-page.jsx`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [rewrites](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) in your `next.config.js` to make a specific URL point to a specific page:

```js
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/About/About",
        destination: "/about-page",
      },
    ];
  },
};
```

If you want to export your app with `next export`, then you can rather use [exportPathMap](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/exportPathMap) :

```js
module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
  exportPathMap: async function () {
    return {
      "/": { page: "/" },
      "/about-page": { page: "/about-page" },
      "/About/About": { page: "/about-page" },
    };
  },
};
```

Do not forget to set `trailingSlash: true` or your custom paths without .html will not work.

You can remove the line `"/about-page": { page: "/about-page" },` to make your about page only accessible from `/About/About`.